# Cast all specific datatype columns into other datatypes programatically in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am programmatically trying to convert datatypes of columns and running into some coding issues.

I modified the code used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41918809/dropping-columns-by-data-type-in-scala-spark) for this.

Data >> any numbers being read as strings.

Code >>

```
import org.apache.spark.sql
raw_data.schema.fields
    .collect({case x if x.dataType.typeName == "string" => x.name})
    .foldLeft(raw_data)({case(dframe,field) => dframe(field).cast(sql.types.IntegerType)})
```

Error >>

```
<console>:75: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
    (which expands to)  org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
           .foldLeft(raw_data)({case(dframe,field) => dframe(field).cast(sql.types.IntegerType)})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the result of `dframe(field).cast(sql.types.IntegerType)` in the `foldLeft` is a column, however, to continue the iteration a dataframe is expected. In the link where the code is originally from `dframe.drop(field)` is used which does return a dataframe and hence works.

To fix this, simply use `withColumn` which will adjust a specific column and then return the whole dataframe:

```
foldLeft(raw_data)({case(dframe, field) => dframe.withColumn(field, dframe(field).cast(sql.types.IntegerType))})
```