# How to drop all columns with type NullType in Spark Scala?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to drop all columns with data type `NullType` including columns that exist in nested columns(ArrayType or StructType). I found a solution ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41919383/6645617)) that drop columns based on their data type but it does not work on nested columns!

How can I somehow change below script that works on nested columns as well?

```
df.schema.fields
    .collect({case x if x.dataType.typeName == "null" => x.name})
    .foldLeft(df)({case(dframe,field) => dframe.drop(field)})
```

Thank you in advance.